# How do I draw a member from a class onto a window c++

Tags: c++, class, sfml

I made a character class for the player, and I want to add a player member to the class then draw the player. I am using sfml and xcode. The error I am getting is: No matching member function for call to 'draw' on the: window.draw(player); line. It looks like I need to put a sprite object into .draw() so how do I make player sprite that is part of the class and draw it onto the window? I am new to c++ and sfml so any help is very much appreciated thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace std;



class Character{

public:
    string sprite;
    int health;
    int defense;
    int speed;
    int experience;
    bool move;
    int x_pos;
    int y_pos;
    sf::Texture texture;

    //Constructor - Ran everytime a new instance of the class is created
    Character(string image){
        health = 100;
        defense = 100;
        speed = 100;
        experience = 0;
        x_pos = 0;
        y_pos = 0;

        texture.loadFromFile(image);
        sf::Sprite sprite;
        sprite.setTexture(texture);
        sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, 0, 100, 100));
        sprite.setPosition(x_pos, y_pos);
    }
    //Destructor - Ran when the object is destroyed
    ~Character(){

    }
    //Methods
    void forward();
    void backward();
    void left();
    void right();
    void attack();
};

void Character::forward(){
    cout << "Go Forward";
}
void Character::backward(){
    cout << "Go Backward";
}
void Character::left(){
    cout << "Go Left";
}
void Character::right(){
    cout << "Go Right";
}

Character player("/Users/danielrailic/Desktop/Xcode /NewGame/ExternalLibs/Player.png");


int main() {
    // insert code here...
    int windowWidth = 1150;
    int windowHeight = 750;
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(windowWidth, windowHeight ), "Awesome Game" );

    while(window.isOpen()){
        window.draw(player);
        window.display();
        window.setFramerateLimit(60);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make Character inherit from sf::Drawable and implement the pure virtual function/s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply add a member function that would return your player's sprite:

```
sf::Sprite Character::getSprite() {
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    sprite.setTexture(texture);
    sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, 0, 100, 100));
    sprite.setPosition(x_pos, y_pos);
    return sprite;
}
```

Then pass the result to `window.draw`:

```
window.draw(player.getSprite());
```

Alternatively, you could invert the dependency and make the player responsible for all the drawing:

```
void Character::draw(sf::RenderWindow& w) {
    w.draw(...);
}
```

There are other approaches, and the choice depends largely on a lot of external factors. This should get you started, though.

Comment: Oh I see now. That is a lot simpler than I thought thank you very much

Comment: @DapperDaniel please, instead of editing your question title, mark this answer as *accepted*. That's the proper way to mark questions as solved.